# cannot create a wcf web service with https endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, https

I would like to enable my wcf service with https endpoints. but I only get http addresses, even though I set the security mode to transport. what else should I change/add to get this working? thanks a lot

edit: I am on IIS 6 and here is the secure binding info from the server.

```
ServerBindings                  : (LIST) (1 Items)
  "10.1.0.195:80:hw.hello.com"

SecureBindings                  : (LIST) (2 Items)
  "10.1.0.195:443:hw.hello.com"
  "81.212.201.9:443:"



<wsdl:service name="HW">
 <wsdl:port name="webBinding_IHWMerkezWS" binding="tns:webBinding_IHWMerkezWS">
  <soap12:address location="http://hw.world.com/HWPostBox/services/HW.asmx" /> 
 <wsa10:EndpointReference>
  <wsa10:Address>http://hw.world.com/HWPostBox/services/HW.asmx</wsa10:Address> 
 <Identity xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity">
  <Dns>localhost</Dns> 
  </Identity>
  </wsa10:EndpointReference>
  </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>



<wsHttpBinding>
 <binding name="webBinding">
   <security mode="Transport">
   <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""></transport>
   <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
   </security>
 </binding>



</wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>      
      <service name="HWPostBox.HW" behaviorConfiguration="HWPostBox.HWBehavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingName="webBinding" contract="CRLHW.HWWS.IHWMerkezWS">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="HWPostBox.HWBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Have you added https binding in IIS?

Comment: can you please elaborate? (there is an ssl certificate available on IIS and I call the wsdl file on an https address.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I had to change bindingName attribute to bindingConfiguration.

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding"...>
</endpoint>
```

Thanks a lot.